# How to pass getAttribute with response()->json to ajax result on Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have small laravel function called from ajax. Then I have to return result to ajax result. For example

```
Public function Edit(Request $request){
        $user = User::find($request->id);
       //.........
        return response()->json($user);
}
```

But I have problem on 'salary' property because of It getting from getSalaryAttribute method

```
public function getPositionnameAttribute(){
   ...........
}
```

So, at the ajax result return 'undefined', that reasonable because 'salary' property does not exist. I do not need to made specific collection to handle only salary parameter.

Any advise or guidance would be greatly appreciated, Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options:

1. add `protected $appends = ['salary']` to your model

or

2. append it on run time: `$user->append('salary')->toArray();`

Check out the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Comment: Dear Rizky Arlin, That's amazing &Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add this attribute to `$appends` array.

**Model**

```php
protected $appends = ['position_name'];
```

NOTE: The $hidden and $appends feature (written above) is for modeling of JSON data and will not effect blade access to properties and/or model renderings.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

Comment: Dear Tharaka Dilshan, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Appending At Run Time add this attribute to $attributes array,

The append method. Or, you may use the setAppends method to override the entire array of appended properties for a given model instance.

```
return $user->append('salary')->toArray();

return $user->setAppends(['salary'])->toArray();
```

Comment: Dear ghanshyam nakiya, Thanks.